# How to Calculate RPM 12V DC Motor 100rpm w/Encoder

Tags: c, arduino-uno

I have tried to find pulse this way in arduino uno. You can see the coding I have tried and this is also a sample image of the motor encoder.

[image]

```
//The sample code for driving one way motor encoder
const byte encoder0pinA = 2;//A pin -> the interrupt pin 0

const byte encoder0pinB = 4;//B pin -> the digital pin 4

byte encoder0PinALast;

int duration;//the number of the pulses

boolean Direction;//the rotation direction 


void setup()

{  
  Serial.begin(57600);//Initialize the serial port

  EncoderInit();//Initialize the module
}

void loop()

{

  Serial.print("Pulse:");

  Serial.println(duration);

  duration = 0;

  delay(100);

}

void EncoderInit()

{

  Direction = true;//default -> Forward  

  pinMode(encoder0pinB,INPUT);  

  attachInterrupt(0, wheelSpeed, CHANGE);

}

void wheelSpeed()

{

  int Lstate = digitalRead(encoder0pinA);

  if((encoder0PinALast == LOW) && Lstate==HIGH)

  {

    int val = digitalRead(encoder0pinB);

    if(val == LOW && Direction)

    {

      Direction = false; //Reverse

    }

    else if(val == HIGH && !Direction)

    {

      Direction = true;  //Forward

    }

  }

  encoder0PinALast = Lstate;

  if(!Direction)  duration++;

  else  duration--;
}
```

I already know pulse, but i don't know how to calculate the rpm of this motor. 
    How to calculate rpm already known pulse?
    Can anyone help me find this way out, I would be very grateful if anyone wants to help me.

Comment: approximately `(duration/100)*60*1000)/pulses_per_turn` If `duration` is calculated correctly....but unfortunately for you it isn't...

Comment: Why do you put a blank line between every line of your code?

Comment: Thank you in advance, this code is just I press "Enter". So it looks empty,but actually interconnected the code. Then do you think I put where the code you give it?